# How Can I pass $role->name into function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I'm using the Laravel Datatables plugin and I would like to pass the ROLE variable into the function so I can access it.

$roles = \Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::all();

```
    if (!empty($roles)) :

        foreach ($roles as $role) :

            $dt->addColumn($role->name, function ($user) {
                return $this->generate_user_role_button($user, $role->name);
            });

            $rawColumns[] = $role->name;

        endforeach;

    endif;
```

The code above does not work but I'm wondering what would be the solution.

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass the variables into the closure you need `use`.

For more info on this refer to the PHP docs for [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```
if (!empty($roles)) :

    foreach ($roles as $role) :

        $dt->addColumn($role->name, function () use ($user, $role) {
            return $this->generate_user_role_button($user, $role->name);
        });

        $rawColumns[] = $role->name;

    endforeach;

endif;
```

Comment: will this work even though addColumn only accepts 1 param in the function?

Comment: The anonymous function is just executed to get $content for the addColumn, so you can do whatever you want with it. See the below from the package, assuming you are using yajra/laravel-datables. https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/blob/7.0/src/Engines/BaseEngine.php#L205

Comment: thank you so much :) works!, i refactored it like this as I was getting an error: foreach ($roles as $role) :

                $dt->addColumn($role->name, function ($user) use ($role) {
                    return $this->generate_user_role_button($user, $role);
                });

                $rawColumns[] = $role->name;

            endforeach;